# How can I submit multiple textviews to Firebase using android studio

Tags: android, database, firebase

I have an app and I want to send multiple textviews to Firebase at once. However it only sends one textview at a time to Firebase. For example I have the following textviews:

1. 2 Chicken Burger
2. 2 Kebab wrap
3. 1 ice cream
4. 1 biscuits
5. 1 lamb doner

but when I submit them to Firebase, i only get this in return:

1. LcSw4gmPVjCS_tSM-ok foodId:
2. -LcSw4gmPVjCS_tSM-ok" foodOrder: "1 Biscuits @ £1.99 = £1.99"

So only biscuits has been sent. The other 4 textviews aren't being submitted

I tried to play around with the class constructor but cant figure it out

this is my data class

```
package com.example.aa1172.the_improved_almighty_project;

public class Data {

    String foodId;
    String foodOrder;

    public Data() {

    }

    public Data(String foodId, String foodOrder) {
        this.foodId = foodId;
        this.foodOrder = foodOrder;
    }

    public String getFoodId() {
        return foodId;
    }

    public String getFoodOrder() {
        return foodOrder;
    }
}
```

This is my code for for the data sending function, This code is inside my main activity

```
    public void send_data() {


        String id = dbref.push().getKey();
        String chicken = varChickenBurgerTotal.getText().toString();
        String kebab = varkebabTotal.getText().toString();
        String lamb = varLambDonerTotal.getText().toString();
        String biscuits = varBiscuitsTotal.getText().toString();
        String icecream = varIceCreamTotal.getText().toString();


        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(chicken) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(kebab) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(icecream) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(biscuits) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(lamb)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Food order sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            // switch (!TextUtils.isEmpty(chicken) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(kebab) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(icecream) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(biscuits) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(lamb))


            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(chicken)) {


                Data mydata = new Data(id, chicken);

                dbref.child(id).setValue(mydata);


            }

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(kebab)) {


                Data mydata = new Data(id, kebab);

                dbref.child(id).setValue(mydata);


            }
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(lamb)) {


                Data mydata = new Data(id, lamb);

                dbref.child(id).setValue(mydata);


            }
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(icecream)) {


                Data mydata = new Data(id, icecream);

                dbref.child(id).setValue(mydata);


            }
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(biscuits)) {


                Data mydata = new Data(id, biscuits);

                dbref.child(id).setValue(mydata);


            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No order is being sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
```

What I need is for all textviews to be sent to the Firebase database when I click the submit button, all at the same time. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a data class like this.

```
 public class Data {

    String chicken;
    String kebab;
    String lamb;
    String biscuits;
    String icecream;

    public Data() {

    }

    public Data(String chicken, String kebab, String lamb, String biscuits,      String icecream) {
        this.chicken = chicken;
        this.kebab = kebab;
        this.lamb= lamb;
        this.biscuits= biscuits;
        this.icecream = icecream;

    }

    //set here getter and setter method
}
```

and then

```
 public void send_data() {

   //You can validate your data here as well. On succesfully validation
   //create new object of Data and push it frebase
   Data mydata = new Data("chicken 5 kg", "kebab 5 kg", "lamb 5 kg", "biscuit 2 pkt", "icecream 300gm")


    String id = dbref.push().getKey();
    dbref.child(id).setValue(mydata);

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

To have only a single call to the database, you can do this:

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(chicken)) {
    mydata = new Data(id, chicken);
}
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(kebab)) {
    mydata = new Data(id, kebab);
}
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(lamb)) {
    mydata = new Data(id, lamb);
}
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(icecream)) {
    mydata = new Data(id, icecream);
}
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(biscuits)) {
    mydata = new Data(id, biscuits);
}

if (mydata != null) {
    dbref.child(id).setValue(mydata);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Food order sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "No order is being sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

This will only set a single item type though, since your `Data` class can only hold a single type.

If you want to store multiple item types, you'll either have to change the `Data` class, or store multiple `Data` objects. The latter is the most flexible, so you'd do that with:

```
List<Data> orders = new List<Data>();
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(chicken)) {
    orders.add(new Data(id, chicken));
}
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(kebab)) {
    orders.add(new Data(id, kebab));
}
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(lamb)) {
    orders.add(new Data(id, lamb));
}
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(icecream)) {
    orders.add(new Data(id, icecream));
}
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(biscuits)) {
    orders.add(new Data(id, biscuits));
}

System.out.println("Got "+orders.size()+" orders");
if (orders.size() > 0) {
    dbref.child(id).setValue(orders);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Food order sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "No order is being sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I implemented your solution but the size of "orders" isn't going up. It stays at 0. There are no typos or errors. The "add" method works but it isn't increasing the size of the object

Comment: That makes little sense. I added a simple `println` statement. Can you add that too, and then see what shows up in the logcat?

Comment: 04-15 17:03:20.826 20837-20837/com.example.aa1172.the_improved_almighty_project I/System.out: Got 0 orders

Comment: I even copied and pasted your code to be absolutely sure. I selected 5 items and it isn't adding any of them to the object. it skips the condition and runs the "else" condition

Comment: I ran the debugger and I'm watching the "orders" object and the size remains at 0 even though the "add" method is called upon it. i don't know how to fix this

Comment: Sorry, if `order.add(..)` gets called, `orders.size()` remaining `0` makes no sense to me whatsoever. Hopefully somebody else sees what's going wrong.

Comment: I got the solution from the other comment. Thanks chief

Answer (score 0):

You only have two constructor in your Data.class. Try following Prafulla Nayak's answer and it will be done. Also in your Data.class, you have FoodOrder which is a string. If you want to put in an array list, try to use list<>.